# Navigation Drawer hamburger menu icon change issue

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, toolbar, hamburger-menu

I am unable to change the default icon of hamburger menu. I am using navigation components. Here's the code am trying in my Home_Activity.kt file

```
 val navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.navController

        setSupportActionBar(binding.newToolbar)


        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.notification)


        notification = findViewById(R.id.notification)
```

Below is the actiivty_home.xml code

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/new_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#8049422E"
        android:backgroundTint="#8049422E"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navigationIcon="@null"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/chat"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_chat_main"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/notification"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/notification"
                android:layout_width="22dp"
                android:layout_height="22dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
                android:src="@drawable/notification"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Image of the related issue :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujNLX.jpg)

I was expected a customised menu icon but everytime it throws up the same default one

Comment: Did you try [setIcon](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/ActionBar#setIcon(int)) or [setNavigationIcon](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/Toolbar#setNavigationIcon(int)) ?

Comment: Nothing happens with either